# Making my images span across the website by creating a class

Tags: css, image, class, html

I've been wanting to span my images across my website.
I am pretty new to css so I probably have bunch of mistakes.

I defined my class here:

```
#galleryphotos { float:left; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
.displayphoto { float:left;  border: none;  margin: none; padding: none; }
img.displayphoto {   clear: both;  display: block; position: relative;  width: 100%;}
```

And here I display it:

```
<div id="galleryphotos"> 
    <div class="displayphoto"> <img src="images/property/DSC_0006.JPG" class="displayphoto"> </div>
    <div class="displayphoto"> <img src="images/property/DSC_0007.JPG" class="displayphoto"> </div>
</div>
```

A bit of zooming happens when I resize the browser but not very much.
Any ideas what it is that I'm doing wrong?

p.s. I just fiddled around and found a solution: I moved the  `clear: both;  width: 100%;` to `.displayphoto`

Comment: Your images will get both `.displayphoto` rules applied.

Comment: If you can post a jsfiddle example, it would be easier to diagnose. But, when you float the `.displayphoto` to the left the default `width: 100%` of a div no longer takes effect, which I believe could be your scaling issue for your image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/V3D6a/  Here is Tom's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code and you have provided you don't need to float the images. Setting them as "block" elements will keep them on their own line and the "width:100%;" will allow them to fill and scale to the width of the container as you resize the window.

CSS

```
#galleryphotos {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
.displayphoto {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   border:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="galleryphotos">
    <img src="images/property/DSC_0006.JPG" class="displayphoto" alt="DSC_0006" />
    <img src="images/property/DSC_0007.JPG" class="displayphoto" alt="DSC_0007" />
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/jonathanglyn/waKSv](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanglyn/waKSv/)

Should you want to add padding around the images while maintaining the scaling of the photos, you can do this by adding a margin to the "galleryphotos" container and a margin bottom to the "displayphoto" class.

Also, where possible you should always include the [ALT tag](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-accessibility/image-alt-text.shtml) to images to aid the accessibility of your website